# How to show last commented post in mysql where are two tables involved? (post and comments)

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have an internal site forum. A very simple one that has just two tables: one for the forum posts and another for the forum contents.

I do show a list of all posts and when the user clicks on each item it goes to the post with all its comments.

The forum posts are ordered by post date (in descending order), but I would like to order by update date, so not only the new posts **but the new commented posts as well appear at the top**.

### These are the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE foro (
    foroID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int(11) NOT NULL,
    estado char(7) NOT null DEFAULT 'abierto',
    asunto char(200) NULL,
    fecha char(25) NULL,
    deprecated_userID int(11) NULL,
    deprecated_nodeID int(11) NULL,
    texto text null
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE foroComentarios (
    comentarioID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    foroID int(11) NOT NULL,
    userID int(11) NOT NULL,
    fecha char(25) NULL,
    deprecated_userID int(11) NULL,
    deprecated_nodeID int(11) NULL,
    texto text null
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### And here is how I show the forum posts now:

```
    SELECT  foro.foroID, 
            foro.userID AS userid, 
            foro.asunto, 
            foro.estado, 
            foro.fecha,
            usuarios.userID, usuarios.docFoto,
            usuarios.userApellido, usuarios.userNombres
    FROM foro JOIN usuarios
    ON foro.userID = usuarios.userID
    ORDER BY foro.fecha DESC
```

I think that I should use subqueries for that, but I've tried several ways and the only thing that I get is a list of duplicated posts. **Is there a way to achieve that without modifying the table's structures?**

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought that providing a query example of what I'm doing was enough as a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)"?

Comment: So, now you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to create a proper MCVE for my question, I've found the solution :)

So, just in case it helps someone someday, this is what it worked for me:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT foro.foroID, 
            foro.userID AS userid, 
            foro.asunto, 
            foro.estado, 
            usuarios.userID, usuarios.docFoto,
            usuarios.userApellido, usuarios.userNombres,
            foro.fecha AS fechaP,
            foroComentarios.fecha AS fechaC,
            IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(
                    foroComentarios.fecha 
                    ORDER BY foroComentarios.fecha 
                    DESC 
                    SEPARATOR ','),
                    foro.fecha) fechaX
    FROM foro JOIN usuarios
    ON foro.userID = usuarios.userID
    LEFT JOIN foroComentarios
    ON foro.foroID = foroComentarios.foroID
    GROUP BY foro.foroID
    ORDER BY fechaX DESC
```

After that I just take the fechaX field (explode it to get the latest unix time number), and use it to order the list.